# How to read from a text file using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using this code to read data from a text file

```
$.ajax({
    url: "History.txt",
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data) {
        alert("My Data :: " + data);
        //process text file line by line
        $('#div').html(data.replace(/n/g, ""));
    }
});
```

This code runs fine in IE . But not working in Chrome. Anyone got any idea why this is happening?

Comment: `url` is wrong. Change it to `url : "localhost/History.txt",` with your server address

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But I am not using any web server here. :( . It is a html file which wants to access a local file. Is it at all possible? Sorry if my question is too stupid :(

Comment: Ajax is an `http` request and doesn't work with `file:` protocols!